# Can I hide from "Shared with Me" the documents others users shared with me?

Tags: google-drive

My problem is that I dont want have a "Shared with Me" folder cluttered with all the docs people shared with me. I prefer move those docs to specifics folders in my folder tree.

I did that and all is fine except that the docs beside be showed in the folder to which I moved them in, appear in the "Shared with Me" folder too. How can I hide the documents that others users shared with me from the "Shared with Me" folder after I moved them out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the docs from the `Shared with Me` folder after move them to another folder in the folder tree don't remove the moved document too. Resuming... for me worked:

1. Moving the doc in the `Shared with Me` folder to another folder.
2. Delete the doc on the `Shared with Me` folder.
3. Enjoy a not cluttered `Shared with Me` folder while having things shared with me organized in the folders that I want.

At the end, seem that the `Move to...` feature for items inside the `Shared with Me` folder don't work like it does in others folders, I mean, `Move to...` not move the folders/files but just copied them, that is why one can remove the source without delete the destination after a `Move to...` from the `Shared with Me` folder.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be witty:   the poster is asking to have his cake and eat it to.  Google simply doesn't provide any mechanism to organise "shared with me" files at the current time.    Any work-around with the Move function may well cause problems with the future versions of Drive.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ Can you explain in what way the work around I described can cause problems?

Comment: None that I know of today.    But Drive is designed around the idea that the Shared With Me folder contains a sortable list of all the documents that have been shared with you, and the idea that you will use search, not folder structures, to find the one you want. There are no guarantees that a alter version of Drive will not change how it handles files if you attempt to "move" them from the Shared with Me list.   And as Google often don't announce feature changes, you could do some damage.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ Where do you read that Google idea behind the "Shared With Me" exclude folder organization and that in upcoming versions of Drive they could undo the folders arrange you did in this version using the "Move to..." feature? Or are those just supposition? I really doubt that Google suddenly will rearrange yours folders in new versions of Drive for the fact that you move some of them from the "Shared with Me" special folder.

Comment: I don't read it anywhere.   But my experience with Google products is that the don't share details of the product roadmap, far less detailed changes with us, unless those changes involve standard uses.   You are proposing a non-standard use, and that is always a risk.  You could easily find that one day deleting a file from the Shared with Me list revokes your access to it.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ I got your point, but still not think that you can talk about a *non-standard* use without read it from Google. Beside, the problem that you describe just come with a backward compatibility break in the UI (the same UI action do something today and another thing tomorrow), and I really don't expect Google do that anytime.